# Where can I find good instructions on how to add in-app subscriptions to my Android app using Google Market Billing APIv2?

Tags: android, in-app, subscriptions

I have been trying to make sense of Android's developer docs concerning the in-app subscriptions capability that was included in the Market Billing API v2 earlier this year.  All of the documentation seems to talk about in-app billing and only briefly mentions subscriptions implementation and testing.

I have downloaded the Dungeons sample application which does not implement subscriptions.  I have set up a test app which defines two of my own subscription products.  When I purchased a $9.99/year subs, it did charge me.  I failed to store the purchase token correctly, so there was no actual delivery (my fault).  I then attempted to refund my order through Google Checkout so I could restart the test, and it did not give me a refund.  It actually charged my credit card, and I did not capture the purchase token, so there is no way for me to revive the old transaction that I know of.  Does anyone know of any VERY CLEAR documentation of the process for Google Play in-app subscriptions and a solid and repeatable testing process?  The android documentation on this one is tough for me.  I have been using the following links as reference thus far:

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Thank you for any help that anyone can provide.